# How to check if the app has Accessibility Access?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm working on a macOS Objective-C application that interacts with trackpad and mouse. This kind of interaction needs Accessibility Control. The problem is that if user unticks the app (while it's running) in `System Preferences` > `Security & Privacy` > `Privacy` > `Accessibility`, it prevents user to work with trackpad and mouse properly, so making hard even to quit the app.

The only thing that I could manage to do with this problem is running Terminal via Spotlight Search and doing `killall`.

I need the app to stop itself if there is no Accessibility permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `AXIsProcessTrusted` to determine if you are trusted for accessibility. I'm not aware of any callback or notification when the setting changes, but it sounds like you could just poll every second or so, and exit your app if the function starts to return false.

[AXIsProcessTrusted](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1460720-axisprocesstrusted?language=objc)